# jQuery .html() function removing text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to edit the div's text, but when i use my function to update the rowcount, everytime the text vanihes completely. Would by nice if you could also explain why.
Thanks in advance.

My update function:

```
var rowCountF = $('#tablef tr').length;
var rowCountV = $('#tablev tr').length;

var ftext = "Teilnehmer (" + String(rowCountF) + ")";
var vtext = "Teilnehmer (" + String(rowCountV) + ")";

$("#divf").html(ftext);
$("#divv").html(vtext);
```

My div layer:

```
<div id="divf"class="tableheader"> <h2>Teilnehmer</h2> </div>
```

Code for divf:

```
<div id="divf"class="tableheader"> <h2>Teilnehmer</h2> </div>
```

Comment: It is doing exactly what you are telling it to do: replace everything within the `#divf` with the HTML `Teilnehmer (x)` (with `x` being a number). You are telling it to replace the `<h2>` with the text...

Comment: Shouldn't it be '$("#divf h2").html(ftext);'?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/html/ see the docs. This always replaces all contents of the target element with the provided content.

Comment: Also, there should be a space between the id and the class attrubite on your div

Comment: Just a side note. You don't need to put `rowCountF`/`rowCountV` in primitive wrapper objects. Those numeric values are already getting converted in your second pair of variable assignments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are actually replacing the contents of the `div` itself with your text. This means the heading disappears and there is only plain text.

Probably you wanted to replace the heading contents:

```
$("#divf h2").html(ftext);
$("#divv h2").html(vtext);
```

This will select the `h2` elements inside the `divs` and hence will update only the text inside the headings.

The result will look like the following:

```
<div id="divf"class="tableheader"> <h2>Teilnehmer (987)</h2> </div>
<div id="divf"class="tableheader"> <h2>Teilnehmer (123)</h2> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.html()` *sets* the HTML, meaning it replaces anything that's currently there. If you want to *add* to the HTML, you'll need to set the HTML to what's already there *plus* what you're adding, like so:

```
var rowCountF = $('#tablef tr').length;
var rowCountV = $('#tablev tr').length;

var ftext = "Teilnehmer (" + rowCountF + ")";
var vtext = "Teilnehmer (" + rowCountV + ")";

//Get already-existing HTML
var divfHtml = $("#divf").html();
var divvHtml = $("#divv").html();

//Set the new HTML to the existing + the new text
$("#divf").html(divfHtml + ftext);
$("#divv").html(divvHtml + vtext);
```

If you only want to replace the heading, then just target the `<h2>` as [Martin Zikmund](https://stackoverflow.com/users/732221/martin-zikmund) suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41000889/2026606).

Comment: This isn't right, it will add the new count outside the old `<h2>`, and leave the `<h2>` the way it is. And every time it runs it will get longer and longer.

Comment: @Barmar OP never specified that he wanted the text within his `<h2>`. He said "Everytime I update, the text vanishes completely.", leading me to believe he wanted the text to be cumulative. He also said "I am trying to update **the div's** text". The `<h2>` update was merely an assumption that turned out to be correct, and my answer was posted before OP made that clear. For all we know from OP's question, he wanted a running list of ID's underneath his `<h2>`. I answered the question that was *asked*, and in the event the `<h2>` assumption was correct, I included a reference to that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the h2 for the div. using `.html()` will replace ALL of the html inside the #divf which in this case means it will replace the h2

```
$("#divf h2").html(ftext);
$("#divv h2").html(vtext);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/qhef0toc/3/